# How to add name as show[xyz], show[abc], etc for multiple checkboxes in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hii... I want multiple checkboxes to be displayed as and so on...name="show[adgroups]", how can i do this using zend form code?? Please see below example how I wanted my output to be viewed:

Instructions

```
<div class="fieldgrp"> 
<label for="show_adgroups">Campaign/Ad-groups</label> 
<div class="field"><input type="checkbox" name="show[adgroups]" id="show_adgroups" class="" value="adgroups" checked="checked" /></div> 
</div> 
<div class="fieldgrp"> 
<label for="show_keywords">Keywords</label> 
<div class="field"><input type="checkbox" name="show[keywords]" id="show_keywords" class="" value="keywords" checked="checked" /></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any easy way of achieving what you want. Normally, MultiCheckbox will use names such as show[], show[]. In addition, setName method of an element, filters out any square brackets. Therefore, I think that the only way to do as you want, would be to write custom MultiCheckbox element and associated view helper.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the "why", you can achieve what you want using a [subform](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms).

Simply name the subform "show" and add your "adgroups" and "keywords" checkboxes to it.

```
$form = new Zend_Form;
$show = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$show->addElement('checkbox', 'adgroups', array(
    'label'   => 'Campaign/Ad-groups',
    'checked' => true
));
$show->addElement('checkbox', 'keywords', array(
    'label'   => 'Keywords',
    'checked' => true
));
$form->addSubForm($show, 'show');
```